# React async/await prop not re-rendering in child component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

Link to CodeSandBox of what I am experiencing:

### https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chaum-eu1le6?file=/src/About.js

I am stuggling to figure out why a component will not re-render after a state changes. In this example, it is an array prop given from App.js to About.js.

- a fetch request happens three times in a useEffect. Each time, it pushes it to stateArr before finally setState(stateArr)

```js
      fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
          stateArr.push(res);
        });
      fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
          stateArr.push(res);
        });
      fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
          stateArr.push(res);
        });
      setState(stateArr);
```

- The About component is imported, and the useState variable is passed to it as a prop.

```js
  return (
    <div>
      <About arrayProp={state} />
    </div>
  );
```

- Finally, About.js destructs the prop, and arrayProp.map() is called to render each array item on the page.

```js
const About = ({ arrayProp }) => {
  const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      {arrayProp.map((e) => (
        <div key={e.length}>
          <h6>Break</h6>
          {e.fact}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

**In the CodeSandBox example, I've added a button that would manually re-render the page by incrementing a number on the page.**
The prop should prompt a component re-render after the fetch requests are completed, and the state is changed.

Comment: You're calling `setState(stateArr);` before the `fetch` complete. Or rather, there's no connection between the promises resolving and your setState call.

Comment: @HenryEcker If this was the case, wouldn't the manual re-render button not work?

Comment: Additionally, there are no `async` declarations nor `await` operators in the source, despite the question title.

Comment: No. Your `setState` is occuring before the fetches complete (which causes a re-render of an empty array and reassigning the state reference to `stateArr`).  You're also updating that same array `stateArr` directly in each promise with `push`. There's only a single `stateArr` so as the fetches resolve they're pushing to the array. When you force the re-render the values have been `push`ed to `stateArr` which is why it appears. [Waiting until all the promises resolve](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-joana-fc8qjo?file=/src/App.js) then calling `setState` is, I think, what you're looking for.

Comment: @outis the fetch requests are asynchronous, but point taken. It's more to emphasize data that is not readily available.

Comment: Possibly covered by "[React Multiple Fetch Requests](//stackoverflow.com/q/60343948/90527)", "[React component doesn't re-render after state change](//stackoverflow.com/q/55544985/90527)"

Comment: @HenryEcker I understand. I was a pushing a promise that was still pending. Thank you for your help. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `useEffect` is not behaving as described.

> Each time, it pushes it to stateArr before finally setState(stateArr)

The individual fetches are not pushing to "before finally" calling `setState`.

> ```jsx
> const [state, setState] = useState([]);
> useEffect(() => {
>     let stateArr = [];
>
>     function getReq() {
>         fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
>             .then((res) => {
>                 return res.json();
>             })
>             .then((res) => {
>                 stateArr.push(res);
>             });
>         fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
>             .then((res) => {
>                 return res.json();
>             })
>             .then((res) => {
>                 stateArr.push(res);
>             });
>         fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
>             .then((res) => {
>                 return res.json();
>             })
>             .then((res) => {
>                 stateArr.push(res);
>             });
>         setState(stateArr);
>     }
>
>     getReq();
> }, []);
> ```

What is actually happening is: fetch 1 is starting, then fetch 2 is starting, then fetch 3 is starting, then `setState(stateArr)` is being called.

There's no guarantee that these fetch will resolve *before* `setState` is called (there's similarly no guarantee that the fetches *won't* complete before calling `setState`). Though, in normal circumstances none of the fetches will resolve before `setState` is called.

So the only thing that's guaranteed is that `state` will be updated to reference the same array as `stateArr`. For this reason, `push`ing to `stateArr` is the same as `push`ing to `state` which is mutating state without using setState. This can cause results to be overwritten on future setState calls *and* it does not cause a re-render.

---

Well then, why does forcing re-render in `About` work?

As each fetch resolves it `push`es values to `stateArr` (which is the same array as is referenced by `state`) for this reason the values *are* in the `state` there's just been nothing to tell React re-render (like a `setState` call).

Here's a small snippet which logs the promises as they complete. It also has a button that will console log the `state` array. (Nothing will ever render here as nothing will cause the state to update despite the `state` array being modified)

```js
// Use import in normal cases; const is how use* are accessed in Stack Snippets
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        let stateArr = [];

        function getReq() {
            fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    stateArr.push(res);
                    console.log('Promise 1 resolves', stateArr);
                });
            fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    stateArr.push(res);
                    console.log('Promise 2 resolves', stateArr);
                });
            fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    stateArr.push(res);
                    console.log('Promise 3 resolves', stateArr);
                });
            console.log('Calling Set State')
            setState(stateArr);
        }

        getReq();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => console.log(state)}>Log State Array</button>
            {state.map((e) => (
                <div key={e.length}>
                    <h6>Break</h6>
                    {e.fact}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

To resolve this, simply wait for all promises to complete with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), then call `setState` with *all* the values.

```jsx
const [state, setState] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
        // Promise 1
        fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        }),
        // Promise 2
        fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        }),
        // Promise 3
        fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        })
    ]).then((newStateArr) => {
        // Wait for all promises to resolve before calling setState
        setState(newStateArr);
    });
}, []);
```

And here's a snippet demoing the result when waiting for all promises to resolve:

```js
// Use import in normal cases; const is how use* are accessed in Stack Snippets
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const App = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        Promise.all([
            // Promise 1
            fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            }),
            // Promise 2
            fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            }),
            // Promise 3
            fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            })
        ]).then((newStateArr) => {
            // Wait for all promises to resolve before calling setState
            setState(newStateArr);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {state.map((e) => (
                <div key={e.length}>
                    <h6>Break</h6>
                    {e.fact}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```